# How do I optimise this java script code with document.?

Tags: javascript, html, do-while

I'm newbie in JS and don't understand how `do..while` and etc work here. How do I optimise this code? Is it even right what I'm doing (setting variables `a[...]`, `b[...]` inside every element with id `a1-7`? I have a `list group` with `list items` inside with `#a1-7`, `#b1-7`. What I'm doing is setting data-value with value to replace data-target (other text element) with data-value.

```
document.getElementById('a1').setAttribute('data-value', a[0])
document.getElementById('a2').setAttribute('data-value', a[1])
document.getElementById('a3').setAttribute('data-value', a[2])
document.getElementById('a4').setAttribute('data-value', a[3])
document.getElementById('a5').setAttribute('data-value', a[4])
document.getElementById('a6').setAttribute('data-value', a[5])
document.getElementById('a7').setAttribute('data-value', a[6]);

document.getElementById('b1').setAttribute('data-value', b[0])
document.getElementById('b2').setAttribute('data-value', b[1])
document.getElementById('b3').setAttribute('data-value', b[2])
document.getElementById('b4').setAttribute('data-value', b[3])
document.getElementById('b5').setAttribute('data-value', b[4])
document.getElementById('b6').setAttribute('data-value', b[5])
document.getElementById('b7').setAttribute('data-value', b[6]);
$('[data-target]').on("click", '[data-value]', function() {
  const clicked = $(this).addClass("actived");
  clicked.siblings(".actived").removeClass("actived");
  $(clicked.parent().data('target')).text(clicked.data('value'));
})
```

Also, is there any way to optimise this (there are really much of this)? Maybe some script to fulfill those..?:

```
    <ul class="list-group" id="a" data-target=".descr">
            <li class="list-group-item" id="a1">
<span>
<?php
    echo print_r($tempa[0]["name"], true);
    ?>
</span>
             </li>
<li class="list-group-item" id="a2">
<span>
<?php
    echo print_r($tempa[1]["name"], true);
    ?>
</span>
             </li>
<li class="list-group-item" id="a3">
<span>
<?php
    echo print_r($tempa[2]["name"], true);
    ?>
</span>
           </li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You want to use a loop:

```
const a = ['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6']

for (const i in a) {
    document.getElementById('a' + i).setAttribute('data-value', a[i])
}
```

Also, you can create simple function to make your code a little bit more clean if you need to iterate over several arrays:

```
function setDataValue(id, value) {
    document.getElementById(id).setAttribute('data-value', value)
}

const a = ['val0', 'val1', 'val2', 'val3', 'val4', 'val5', 'val6']

for (const i in a) {
    setDataValue('a' + i, a[i])
}
```

In your PHP code you need to do it the same way:

```
<?php foreach ($tempa as $key => $value): ?>
    <li class="list-group-item" id="a<?php echo $key + 1; ?>">
        <span>
        <?php
            echo $value["name"];
        ?>
        </span>
    </li>
<?php endforeach; ?>
```